# SSIS excel Generate Error

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008, ssis

I am a beginner to SSIS. i have been facing some issues with generating excel using the SSIS. I package generate 10 excel reports in parallel.Excel is generated using a pre formatted excel, and the package copy that template to a given location and the excel is generated on the destination path.The package is called from parent package.That parent package is called using the SQL JOB.Now the problem is when i am executing the package,i am facing some challenges.all the reports are generating but sometimes the generation fails.the failure doesn't happens for all the reports one or two excel file generate fails.

> Description: "External table is not in the expected format.".  End Error  Error: 2017-01-11 22:53:06.32     Code: 0xC020801C     Source: Loan Insource Data Excel Destination [73]     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Loan Insrc Data1" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.  End Error  Error: 2017-01-11 22:53:06.40     Code: 0xC004701A     Source: Loan Insource Data SSIS.Pipeline     Description: component "Excel Destination" (73) failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC020801C.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  22:36:15  Finished: 22:57:22  Elapsed:  1267.15 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

Comment: See if this helps. https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/114399/error-code-0xc0202009-in-ssis.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is classic error come while working with Excel data sources.

To solve

Step 1: Navigate to Project-> [PROJECT_NAME] Properties.

Step 2: Navigate to “Debugging” option from left panel and from Right panel change Run64BitRuntime value to false.

Comment: I have executed the package using the setting using the mentioned settings. but the issue is with when i am executing through the .net code.i am  using SQL Job to execute the package.I have used the 32bit execution settings in the sql job. The report is generating.but sometimes it fails for a single task.but all other task are generating the excel.

Comment: do Above change on you package in BIDS and save the file and replace and the execute... job

Comment: After the change in the settings the package still failed after few run.i m trying to generate 10 excel in parallel.

Comment: i found that the issue is with when i was trying to generate the report between two particular date.for other dates the report had no issues.So i think the issue was with data.I used a table to write the data, the table contained a column with data type Money, i did no conversion to handle that column data, due to this reason the job was failing to generate report. I put a data conversion and handle money in SQl to DT_CY in SSIS and then i created a new template with the new conversion.Now the report is generating.